# Redirect to external URL in GAE PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, url

How would I go about redirecting to an external link <strike>in `GAE`</strike> with `PHP`?

I've tried using `header()`, but the new `URL` is always appended to the current `URL`.

Example:
`header("Location: www.google.com");`
results in a redirect to `www.mydomain.com/www.google.com`

How do I get it to just redirect to a new `URL` completely?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be:

```
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
```

You need to specify the protocol or it will be treated as a directory/file.